# inner exception when using UserId as FK

Tags: c#, userid, inner-exception

this may be a simple problem for some of you, but I am have a difficult time trying to resolve it.

I have a Message.cs class:

```
    public class Message : Audit
        {
            public int MessageId { get; set; }
            public string TextBody { get; set; }


            public string UserId { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("UserId")]
            public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        }
```

I am using entity framework to have secure log ins and etc.
When I post a message, I have set break points to see that the message object that I am sending does contain the UserId, but when db.SaveChanges(); is called, there is an error:

"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.Messages_dbo.AspNetUsers_ApplicationUser_Id\". The conflict occurred in database \"aspnet-ChatApp-20140708035313\", table \"dbo.AspNetUsers\", column 'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

Also, I am using data adapters and interfaces to work with my APIs. 
my MessageDataAdapter for POST looks like this: (EDITTED LOOK BELOW)

```
    public Models.Message PostMessage(Models.Message newMessage)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
        Message message = new Message();
        newMessage.TextBody = message.TextBody;
        newMessage.DateSent = DateTime.Now;
        newMessage.Hidden = message.Hidden;
        newMessage.UserId = user.Id;
        db.Messages.Add(newMessage);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return newMessage;
    }
```

When I set a breakpoint, newMessage contains the necessary data plus the UserId when I am logged in, for I have it authroized so only "Users" can POST to the DATABASE.  However, when it reaches db.SaveChanges that error occurs.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Thank you!

EDIT

this is what I have(I guess what I really want to be able to do is to be able to POST Message containing the UserId of whoever is logged in):

```
    public Models.Message PostMessage(Models.Message newMessage)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
        Message message = new Message();
        message.TextBody = newMessage.TextBody;
        message.DateSent = DateTime.Now;
        message.Hidden = newMessage.Hidden;
        message.UserId = newMessage.UserId;
        db.Messages.Add(message);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return message;
    }
```

My front end HTML has a input type hidden with the value being "User.Identity.GetUserId()" which I want to be POSTed with the Message.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating new user when posting message?

Retrive the old-one from db.AspNetUsers(or db.Users ?). Or if creating new user is really needed, then you must also add user to db.AspNetUsers repository - id will be generated only when you add user to repository. If not, then user.Id property will be default - i.e. 0 for integer type. But there is no user with id=0 in AspNetUsers table. This error says about that.

Comment: I have a user created already, so with the logged in USER, when he or she POSTs a message, I am trying to have the UserId posted with the Message.  So my sql table has a column for User_Id that ASP Identity User gave me already.  Now when I POST, the UserId is null...